# Unable to Load MvxRecyclerView in PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mvvmcross, popupwindow

I am using Mvvmcross in Xamarin Android application.  I am trying to use PopupWindow with RecyclerView to load the items.  However, I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception when displaying the popup . The below is the stack trace

```
[MonoDroid] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[MonoDroid]   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerAdapter.OnCreateViewHolder (Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, System.Int32 viewType) [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross-AndroidSupport\MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView\MvxRecyclerAdapter.cs:155 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+Adapter.n_OnCreateViewHolder_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_I (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_parent, System.Int32 viewType) [0x0000f] in <1c3b474ba0bc45cba6ec33f4b4b4b99a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:19c45b14-7829-49b5-9757-906d8e518696 (intptr,intptr,intptr,int)
```

The below are the code snippet that I am using to display the PopupWindow inside a Fragment.

```
myTextControl.Click += delegate
{
    View contentView = LayoutInflater.From(Activity).Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_filter_dropdown, rootElement, false);
    MvxRecyclerView myRecyclerView = (MvxRecyclerView)contentView.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.rv_function_wash_time);
    myRecyclerView.Id = 1;
    myRecyclerView.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Item1", "Item2"};
    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(contentView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    myRecyclerView.ItemTemplateId = Resource.Id.filterdropdowntemplate;
    popupWindow.SetBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.OutsideTouchable = true;
    popupWindow.ShowAsDropDown(myTextControl, 0, 0);
};
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">
<MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_function_wash_time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</MvxRecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am using MvxRecylerView in various places in all over the application.  I am facing issue only If I try to use it in PopupWindow.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you are not inflating your layout with via a `BindingInflate`. As [line 155](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView/MvxRecyclerAdapter.cs#L155) in `MvxRecyclerAdapter` speaks to requiring a binding context which you are not providing.

```
var contentView = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.custom_filter_dropdown, rootElement);
```